# Как удалить все одинаковые символы из массива символов?

Tags: c, символы, массивы

Например, надо удалить все символы 's' если встречается 's''s'?:
`char ch[]="psssrossgrsasssssms"`

Comment: удалить все символы s из строки в том случае если в ней есть две s подряд ? :) т.е. в вашем примере результат program ?

Comment: Мне хотелось бы узнать как это решить если у меня 27033 символов, и надо удалить там какие то символы по каким то условиям...

Comment: Условия надо знать заранее. Потому что условие "символ - не 'a'" это одно, а условие "символ, перед которым нет символа 'a' на 3 позиции назад, за которым на 8 позиций вперёд нет символа 'b'" - это совсем другое. BTW, пока это писал, подумалось про регекспы. Чем не решение, кстати?

Comment: @Дато, сразу могу посоветовать не удалять "по месту", а делать копию с удаленными символами. 

В конце ее можно просто скопировать на место исходной.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Мне хотелось бы узнать как это решить если у меня 27033 символов, и надо удалить там какие то символы по каким то условиям...

решается написанием алгоритма под каждое условие

вот алгоритм под ваше условие

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
#define STRLEN 20
    char ch[STRLEN]="psssrossgrsasssssms";
    char buf[STRLEN];
    char * bp = buf;
    char oldChar = 0, delChar = 's';

    for (int i = 0; i < STRLEN; i++){
        if ((ch[i] == ch[i + 1]) && (ch[i] == delChar) || ((ch[i] == delChar) && (ch[i] == oldChar))){
            oldChar = ch[i];
            continue;
        }   else {
            *bp = ch[i];
            bp++;
        }

        oldChar = ch[i];
    }

    *bp = 0;

    printf("%s\n", buf);

    return 0;
}
```

---

```
progrsams
Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

Рекурсивно сравниваем i-ый элемент массива с i+1м, если есть повтор, то  копируем всё, кроме i+1, в новый массив и присваиваем ему ссылку старого. И на новый заход (с новым массивом).

Comment: рекурсивно? о_О

Answer (score 0):

Я бы вот так сделал:

```
String str = "aabbcc";
String str1 = "" + str[0];
for (int i = 1; i<str.Length(); i++)
{
    if (str[i] == str[i-1])
    {
        //Ничего не делаем.
    }
    else
    {
        str1 += str[i];
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(str1);
```